# Whats wrong with this animate function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, modal-dialog

I have this function just to animate the div from the top of the page and vieversa when it is closed.

But it works fine when it is opened if I closed it just behaves in an odd way?
Odd way in the sense the footer is closed and then it closes the entire body.

I have a close button and a link to close.
If I use the link it work fine but when it comes to button then it behaves like I mentioned above.

This is my plugin:

```
    (function($){

    // Defining our jQuery plugin

    $.fn.Lighty = function(prop){

        // Default parameters

        var options = $.extend({
            height : "250",
            width : "500",
            title:"JQuery Modal Box Demo",
            description: "Example of how to create a modal box.",
            top: "20%",
            left: "35%",
        },prop);

        return this.click(function(e){
            add_block_page();
            add_popup_box();
            add_styles();
           setTimeout(function() {
          $('.Lighty').animate({top:'toggle'},50);
            },300);
        });

         function add_styles(){
            $('.Lighty').css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'left':options.left,
                'top':options.top,
                'display':'none',
                'max-height': options.height + 'px',
                'width': options.width + 'px',
                'border-bottom':'1px solid #EEE',
                'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
                'background': '#ffffff',
                'z-index':'50',
            });
            $('.close').css({
                'position':'relative',
                'top':'15px',
                'left':'20px',
                'float':'right',
                'display':'block',
                'height':'50px',
                'width':'50px',
                'background': 'url(images/action_delete.png) no-repeat',
            });
        }

         function add_block_page(){
            var block_page = $('<div class="page"></div>');
            $(block_page).appendTo('body');
        }

         function add_popup_box(){
             var pop_up = $('<div class="Lighty"><a href="#" class="close"></a><div class="mainbody"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div><div class="footer"><button class="closebutton">close</button></div></div>');
             $(pop_up).appendTo('.page');

            $('.close,.closebutton').click(function(){
                 $(this).parent().animate({top:'toggle'},50);
                 setTimeout(function() {        
                  $('.page').fadeOut().remove();    
                },300);      
             });

        }

        return this;
     };
})(jQuery);
```

This is how I call it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.Modalbox').Lighty({
                title: 'Simple Dialog',
                description: 'This is a simple modal dialog with title.<br>Write your descrition here.<br>Write Some content here.<br>Write more content here.<br>Write much more content here.'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Live sample on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58jmq/1/)

Comment: Could you prepare a demonstration on jsfiddle.net? Barely anyone will try this locally

Comment: @eclarns-I am in testing mode,So I included within js and I have a seperate css for this :)

Comment: @zerkms-I am on my way with that.First I thought not to keep as many say that links would expire.Anyways I will place it.

Comment: @JuicyScripter-Thanks for the Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your close and closebutton don't have the same parent. The close animates the whole dialog, then removes the dialog. The closebutton animates the footer, then removes the dialog. That's why it's behaving oddly.

```
$('.close,.closebutton').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({top:'toggle'},50); // This should be parent().parent() for .closebutton
    setTimeout(function() {        
        $('.page').fadeOut().remove();    
    },300);      
});
```

Since you have a reference to the div in your javascript, you could also use it instead. I'd also suggest putting the hiding function in animate's callback, instead of setTimeout (so it's executed when the animation ends):

```
pop_up.animate({top:'toggle'},50,function() {
    $('.page').fadeOut().remove();    
});
```

Comment: @mgibsonbr-What you said is I agree and I have just now tried with your code and Still I have the same Issue.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to fact that you first `toggle` the footer, then hide the dialog:

```
$('.close,.closebutton').click(function(){
  // This hides `.footer` which is parent of `.closebutton`
  // Commented this out since it's not needed
  // $(this).parent().animate({top:'toggle'},50);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // This hides the dialog
    $('.page').fadeOut().remove();
  },300);     
});
```

You may just skip the toggling it `$(this).parent().animate({top:'toggle'},50);` since it removed with `.page`...

Comment: I've updated the code by commenting out unneeded toggle operation

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
    $('.close,.closebutton').click(function(){
         $(this).parent().parent().animate({top:'toggle'},50);
         setTimeout(function() {        
          $('.page').fadeOut().remove();    
        },300);      
     });
```

The problem is that you had `$(this).parent().animate({top:'toggle'},50);`